# Export SWC makes big .swc and .swf files

Tags: flash

Using Flash CS5, when activating Export SWC in the Flash Publish Settings, I end up with a much bigger file (500 ko) than when the SWC is not activated (around 100 ko).

Why is the SWC 5 times bigger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that the file size issue was coming from the use of TLF text tool instead of classic text.

When you use TLF, the library has to be included inside the SWC file because it's not built-in inside the Flash Player. You don't need TLF except in given specific situations. See http://forums.adobe.com/message/2913998 for more details on this.

I've changed all the text tool into Classic Text and the file is very small now.

Comment: and yet flash often defaults to TLF text :)

Answer (score 0):

hard to say, but IMHO you know the whole zoo of Flash Player versions and multiply number of Flash IDEs and Flex IDEs and your exported SWC should work fine in most of them, thats why there are much additional information there.

If you are very interested in this question try to **decompile** SWC file which is have a zip structure, so you'll able to research the architecture of this file container.